# Naive Bayes Classification Floating Point Underflow

Tags: floating-point, naivebayes, underflow

Multiplying lots of probabilities in Naïve Bayes can result in floating-point underflow.

```
P(x_1,….,x_n│c) = P(x_1│c).P(x_2│c).P(x_3│c)… … P(x_n |c)
```

Instead of using the above formula (result in floating point underflow), is it more feasible/better to use the formula given below? Or will it truncate information?

```
log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Until the point where underflow or overflow happens, floating-point multiplication is the best behaved of floating-point operations. Besides, in your formula, once underflow is reached, it is known that the end value is small, because the unprocessed factors are less than 1.0 and can only contribute to make the end-result smaller still.

Using a logarithm only seems to reduce accuracy overall, first because of the logarithm itself and second because floating-point addition of numbers of differing magnitudes is **not** well-behaved.

Unless you care about the difference between a probability of 2<sup>-1024</sup> and a probability of zero for some reason that your question does not tell, I do not see why you would want to change the well-behaved multiplications in the first formula into the peril-fraught additions in the second one.

NB: you must have something like 20 factors each of the order of 2<sup>-50</sup> to underflow IEEE 754's binary64 format. If this is the sort of data that you expect and want to handle with accuracy, you might consider going to the 80-bit double-extended format if your compiler makes this type available (for instance as `long double` if you are using C), or to [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org), which I believe uses a full word to represent the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of the probabilities are in a reasonable range, say [2^{-63}, 2^{63}], you can accumulate the product like this:

```
double prod(double *d, int n, int64_t *expo) {
  *expo = 0;
  double ans = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ans *= d[i];
    if (!(i % 16)) {
      int foo = 0;
      ans = frexp(ans, &foo);
      expo += foo;
    }
  }
}
```

The product is then within n/2 ulp of the return value times 2^{`*expo`}.  This code is quite easy to vectorise, and it's also quite easy to write an alternative, faster, `frexp` for this special case that just does bit-fiddling and ignores NaNs/infinities/zeroes/subnormals.

If your platform supports trapping floating-point arithmetic and your input is known to lie in a reasonable, but unknown, range, you can select the stride adaptively with minimal performance impact for large `n` by adding trap handlers for overflow and underflow.  It is probably easiest to do this if you write both the product routine and the trap handler in your platform's assembly language.

If you add logarithms instead, you lose a considerable amount of precision, first by taking the logarithms and second by summing them, that you may or may not care about.  What's worse is that you also lose a considerable amount of *speed* by computing so many logarithms.